# Will this code be able to shred (securely delete) a file?

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I am trying to create a simple file shredder with windows batch-file.
So far, I've written the following:

```
set "Target=File.txt"
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ("%Target%") do (
    fsutil file setzerodata offset=0 length=%%~zf "%%f" >nul
    ren "%%f" "SECURELY DELETED FILE"
    del "%%~dpfSECURELY DELETED FILE" /f /q
)
```

I tried to test this code with a file recover software, but I am not sure if it is safe to tell there is no leftover data. Will this code actually shred a file? (Will deletion of data be irreversible **from normal or bit advanced users**?)

Comment: Don't consider it gone until you've overwritten the entire file a dozen times.

Comment: @SomethingDark So will repeated overwrite ensure the secure deletion? I know experts will somehow recover pieces of data. I am only trying to make sure that the file is not recoverable through simple third-party software.

Comment: If you overwrite the data stored in the system memory location that contains the file enough times, it will be unrecoverable. Ideally, you alternate between overwriting with zeroes and ones.